# Fixed point/lipschitz constant

Tags: real-analysis, functions, fixed-point-theorems, lipschitz-functions

Let $M \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be closed and the mapping $T : M \rightarrow M$ fulfills

$$ |T(x)-T(y)| \leq |x-y| $$
$\forall x,y \in M, x \neq y$

Prove or disprove that T has exactly a fixed point.

So here the Lipschitz constant is L=1, we know that if $L \in (0,1)$, then it is a contraction and the mapping has a fixed point, but how can I prove or disprove here that it has exactly one fixed point?

Comment: What about the special case $ T(x)=x$.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah T(x)=x would have infintitely many fixed points, rights? So can I use this to disprove that statement that it would be having exactly one?

Comment: Yes of course, we  can.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah: thank you very much :)

Comment: You are Welcome.